# Как распределять содержимое в резиновом блоке?

Tags: css3, html, css

Есть блок в котором содержатся несколько блоков:

[image]

Основной блок может изменятся в размерах.
И когда высота основного блока уменьшается  должно получится вот так:

[image]

Как это реализовать? Поддержка старых браузеров не нужна.

Пробовал flexbox но не очень получается [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5hQ8/1/), в первом блоке остается место справа, а его не должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Bootstrap, через media пропишите какой блок будет меняться в размере, а какой будет статическим.